# Does XNA have a built-in GUI library?

Tags: xna, c#, gui

Does such a thing exist or do I have to code one?

My project needs textboxes, buttons, input capture, timings for "press and hold keys" and so on. These are quite standard for a GUI library but hard to code from scratch.

What options do I have?

Comment: You should look at [this](https://bitbucket.org/mindworx/awesomiumxna/wiki/Home). It's made specifically for XNA and is very light weight and versatile.

Comment: Seconded.  I wrote much the same thing as MindWorX.  It is an entirely different way of thinking about UIs in XNA, but it works really well (note though that's only true if you have a good handle on HTML/CSS/Javascript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no form controls available for XNA.  There are 3rd party source code you can get however:

[NeoforceControls](https://github.com/NeoforceControls/XNA)

http://xnainterfaceelements.codeplex.com/

[XNAUI](https://github.com/Rampastring/Rampastring.XNAUI)

** I do not endorse any of these products, nor have I looked at these since I posted this answer back in 2013.*

Comment: May I ask why you removed the links from this answer? They seemed to be useful, and supported the content of the answer rather than making it link-only.

Comment: I didn't want to appear like I was endorsing any products.

Comment: I'd say it's fine to give examples, as long as you disclose whether you're affiliated with any of them.